# Aggregate function for compressed big decimal in Druid

Tags: druid

I have a column in Druid database with the type of Compressed Big Decimal.
I can not use any aggregate functions like sum or even other functions like ABS on this columns.

When I try to use Aggregate functions like Sum like below

Select Sum(my_column) from my_table

it gives me the following errors.

Cannot apply 'SUM' to arguments of type 'SUM(<COMPLEX>)'. Supported form(s): 'SUM()'

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Druid does not support aggregate functions on COMPRESSED BIG DECIMAL.
I had to use API query instead of Native SQL like:

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": "mytable",
  "intervals": [ "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000/2024-01-01T00:00:00.000" ],
  "granularity": "all",
  "aggregations": [
    { "type": "compressedBigDecimalSum", "name": "mycolumn", "mycolumn": "adItemPrice" }
  ],
  "filter": {
    "type": "selector",
    "dimension": "myOtherColumn",
    "value": "myValue"
  },
  "context": {
    "grandTotal": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a great improvement request for Druid SQL functionality. You can request new functionality by creating an issue for the project here: https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/new/choose